# Upgrade Windows Server 2016 1607 to 1709

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016

I've recently spun up a Windows Server 2016 1607 instance in AWS. When checking windows update it only picks up the defender definitions and does not upgrade to 1709, which is the latest upgrade version.

On windows 10 there is the upgrade assistant, when the OS fails to upgrade using the windows updates. Is there anything similar for Windows Server?

I've tried using the same application but it fails on the last check at the start of the process. Any ideas on how to upgrade the server?

What I've attempted thus far:

- Running the windows upgrade assistant
- Running Windows Update
- Searching Technet for any fix that might be out there

Let me know if you need any further information.
Thanks.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsserver/2017/10/26/faq-on-windows-server-version-1709-and-semi-annual-channel/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To move from Windows Server 2016 (or previous versions) to Windows Server, version 1709 you’ll need to run a clean install. In-place upgrades are not supported as Windows Server 2016 is a LTSC release and version 1709 is a Semi-Annual Channel release and they have different support models.

This means that you will either have to wait for AWS to release a new version (1709) or you can create your own VMware or Hyper-V version and import into AWS as an AMI.